# Activity on top of another

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I create an activity that pops from the bottom and does not cover all the screen, just like the Contact details do in the Nexus Dialer.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: BottomSheetDialogFragment

Answer (score 5):

1) create simple activity

2) create style like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Popup" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
</style>
```

3) apply this style in manifest

4) in popup activity `onCreate()` method paste:

```
DisplayMetrics display = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(display);
int width = display.widthPixels;
int height = display.heightPixels;
getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * 0.9), (int) (height * 0.8));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Bottom Sheets

Bottom Sheet is a material design component, that was added to design support library in `version 23.2`. Bottom sheet is a very simple window that displays from the bottom of the screen, and can be used to reveal more content to the user.

Your desired design is too broad to answer.

[Look for example here](https://mayojava.github.io/android/bottom-sheets-android/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve such UI with `Android BottomSheet`. The approach is to have a bottom sticked dialog fragment. [Follow this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031) for implementation instructions as providing complete solution will be too big for this platform.

As far as Activities are concern, I would suggest you to read more Activities and their stack. Activities are `Android Components` and should not be misused just to create UI. Fragments have been introduced for more flexible UI handling. I hope this solves your doubts.